# Is there a better way to call a function in this javascript

Tags: javascript, function, math

I have made a small math game, where a math expression pops up and you have to determine if the results of the problem will be a negative number or a positive one by clicking on a button that has the positive sign or the negative sign([Here is the jsfiddle for it](https://jsfiddle.net/2d1vms82/)). The problem or question I have is in the javascript code toward the bottom. When you see the function that starts off with `document.querySelector('button#positive)` or `document.querySelector('button#negative)`these are the buttons that you click on to determine if the value is positive or negative. And based on the `globalNum[0]`, your choice will determine if your answer is true or not. Now at the end of the function it calls the function `mathP` that creates a new math expression. What I want to know is if there is a better way to call the function instead of putting `globalNum = mathP();` at the bottom.

Javascript

```
document.querySelector('button#start').onclick = function()
{
var counter;
var count = 60;
var mod = 0;
var min = 0;
var finalCount;
//var correct = new Audio('sound/tone-beep.mp3');
//var wrong = new Audio('sound/wrong-action.mp3');
this.style.display = "none";
function countDown()
{  mod = count % 60;


 if ( mod == 0 )
 { min = count / 60;
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML  = min+':00';
 }
 else
 {
  min = count/ 60;
  sec = count % 60;
  min = Math.floor(min);
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML  = (sec < 10)? min+':0'+sec : min+':'+sec;
 }
 count -=1;
   if( count < 0)
  { clearInterval(counter);
    counter = 0;
    count = 0;
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML  = '0:00';
    document.querySelector('button#start').style.display = "block";
        if(document.getElementById('final-score'))
        {
            var score = document.getElementById('score').innerHTML;
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.innerHTML = score;
            document.getElementById('ex1').appendChild(p);
        }
        else
        {
         var elem = document.createElement('h3');
         elem.setAttribute("id","final-score")    
         elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode('The Final Score'));
         document.getElementById('ex1').appendChild(elem);
          elem = document.createElement('p');
         var score = document.getElementById('score').innerHTML;
         elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(score));
         document.getElementById('ex1').appendChild(elem);
        }
    document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 0; 
    console.log(counter);

  }
 return count;
}

counter = setInterval(countDown, 1000);




function mathP()
{
var par = Math.round(Math.random()*(5-2)+2);
var arr = [];
var results = [];
var text, oper, ran, num; 
num = 0;
function value(operator,number,total)
{ if ( operator == "+")
  {
    return  total+number;
  }
  else{

    return total-number;

  }


}

for(var i=0; i < par; i++)
{

 oper = Math.round(Math.random()*(2-1)+1);
 oper = (oper == 1)? '+' : '-';
 ran = Math.round(Math.random()*(10-1)+1);

 if ( i == 0 && oper == '+')
 {
    arr[i] = ran;
 }
 else
 {
    arr[i] = ' '+oper+' '+ran;
 }

 num = value(oper,ran,num);
 if(i < 1)
 {text = arr[i]
 }
 else{

  text += arr[i];
 }

}
document.querySelector('h4').innerHTML = text;


results[0] = num;
results[1] = par;
return results;

}// function mathP

 var globalNum;
     globalNum = mathP(); 


    document.querySelector('button#positive').onclick = function(){
    if (count > 0)
    {
         var a = document.getElementById('score');

        if (globalNum[0] > 0)
        {

         a.innerHTML= globalNum[1] + parseInt(a.innerHTML);
         //correct.play();
         console.log('You were right the value was '+globalNum[0]+' so you get '+globalNum[1]+' points');

        }
        else
        {

         a.innerHTML=  parseInt(a.innerHTML) - globalNum[1] ;
         //wrong.play();
          console.log('You were wrong the value was '+globalNum[0]+' so you get -'+globalNum[1]+' points');
     }

    globalNum = mathP();
    }
    };

    document.querySelector('button#negative').onclick = function(){
    if (count > 0)
    {
        var a = document.getElementById('score');
        if (globalNum[0] < 0)
        {

         a.innerHTML = globalNum[1]+ parseInt(a.innerHTML);
        // correct.play();
         console.log('You were right the value was '+globalNum[0]+' so you get '+globalNum[1]+' points');

        }
        else
        {
         a.innerHTML=  parseInt(a.innerHTML) - globalNum[1];
        // wrong.play();
         console.log('You were wrong the value was '+globalNum[0]+' so you get -'+globalNum[1]+' points');

        }
        globalNum = mathP();
    }
    };


}// button#start onclick
```

Comment: Take a look at [Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (IIFE for short)

Comment: You should make something to handle a zero. I got a "5-5" for one of my questions.

Comment: @wateriswet Yeah, I forgot to do that. I'm eventually going to get to it

Comment: Try to format your code. It helps a long way in organizing and understanding your own code.

Comment: @Ibu what do you mean like adding comments or restructuring it in a object?

Comment: I ran your code under [js beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and it seems like you have all your functions defined inside the click event. I could only see that after I have formatted the structure.

Comment: @Ibu hey thanks for sending me a link to this application